# Drawing a line in OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl

I want to draw a simple line.  So I have this code as shown below. But when I run the code I can't see anything on the form.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            drawLine();   
        }

        private void drawLine() {
            GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES);
            GL.glVertex3f(100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f); // origin of the line
            GL.glVertex3f(200.0f, 140.0f, 5.0f); // ending point of the line
            GL.glEnd(); 
        }
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Assuming the code you've posted is all the code you have, you're missing a lot, like creating an OpenGL window/context, setting the viewport, and specifying the projection matrix. You should read into that a bit more and look into some OpenGL tutorials. OpenGL won't magically work with winforms like this.

Comment: Even if, somehow, it was all working and you could draw to the form, you'd still have the issue of your line being far outside the range of Normalized Device Coordinates, which is [-1, 1] in all 3 axes.

Comment: Yes, this is the only code that I have so far.. I think I need to read a lot more. thanks

Comment: Do you have any complete tutorial even in displaying a simple line?

Comment: From the looks of it, you're using Tao.OpenGL, which I'm assuming has some sort of window/context creation by itself, though I never bothered with Tao.OpenGL since it was abandoned around 2007. I'd recommend, instead, using OpenTK and following the basic tutorials on their website.

Comment: Thanks on this.  I'll try OpenTK then...

Comment: how/when is `drawLine()` called here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default state of OpenGL assumes a viewport size that's equal to the size of the window the context was first attached to. All matrices are identity. So you're effectively drawing in so called normalized device coordinates (NDC) space. In that space the visible viewport has a coordinate range of [-1; 1] in either direction.

Your naive code assumes vertex positions to be in units of pixels. However everything outside the range [-1; 1] lies outside the screen and your "pixel coordinates" are way outside the visible viewport. What you must do is set viewport and projection so that they match your window size, if you want to use pixels as coordinate units.

```
   private void drawLine() {
        GL.glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);

        GL.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        GL.glLoadIdentity();
        GL.glOrtho(0, window_width, 0, window_height, -1, 1);

        GL.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL.glLoadIdentity();

        GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES);
        GL.glVertex3f(100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f); // origin of the line
        GL.glVertex3f(200.0f, 140.0f, 5.0f); // ending point of the line
        GL.glEnd(); 

        GL.glFlush();

        this.SwapBuffer(); // if the form doesn't automatically swap
    }
```